# how to install MySQL without having visual studio

Tags: mysql

when I tried to install MySQL Server with the installer on windows, it didn't install because I don't have Visual Studio. I am developing for Java and don't need Visual Studio anyhow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL isn't related to visual studio in any way.  There is no requirement to have visual studio installed in order for MySQL to install.  Are you installing the right thing?  Are you sure it's complaining about visual studio, and not something like the .net framework?

Answer (score 4):

He is not wrong. He is jus trying to install MySQL by default installation, I was with the same problem too. MySQL requires Visual Studio because the connector for .NET. To solve this, just choose the custom installation and choose the options you need. It will show to you what programs and connectors will be installed and then you will choose the right options to you. For example, I have windows 8.1 and workbench 8.0 doesn't run on my OS version, thus I choose the workbench 6.0 and the right connectors for your needs.
Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing SQL Server with MySQL. They are two different databases. To install MySQL, [you can follow the instructions here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is not needed. You're referring to the VS Runtime Plugin. The installer would take care of that. Just make sure your internet connection is available and proceed with the installer steps. The reason why it's needed is to run the application on windows stack.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you run the installer, you must choose custom setup and remove the visual studio connector.  That is why the installer is asking for visual studio.